# trouble with imports when calling a script with another script

Tags: python, bash, shell, pyqt4

I have several scripts perfectly working by themselves and i would like to create a big pyqt-script which launch those scripts when they are selected.
My only one problem is, every import done on my scripts are not working anymore because of the path. (As the new reference is the pyqt-script and no longer themselves).

I tried to make a movable path but it means changing all my scripts and I would like to be able to "copy/past" my scripts in a file without having to modify them, only the pyqt-script.

I also tried to make a function which open a new terminal with gnome-terminal and launch my script but it is not successful as it keep taking my pyqt-script for reference)

```
os.system("gnome-terminal --tab -e 'tcsh -c \"python /path/script.py; sleep 10)
```

Do you have any idea? even if they work in the same terminal.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what's your file structure? Do you wish to import those modules and use their functionality or manually call them using `os.system()`?

Comment: basically i have a script1 and script2 working perfectly and I want to create a Bigscript which call them but I do not want to change script1 or script2. when I try my code it says there is a problem in import (it is normal as my bigscript is now the reference for import)

Comment: Basically i want it to be simple to add script to the main project as a lot of them are already written. I was mainly thinking about opening a new terminal and launch the script needed.

Comment: Are you trying to import the script1 and script2 into bigscript? or the script1 and script2 has other dependencies that they need to import? Your question is a bit unclear. Maybe give some examples?

Comment: Indeed sorry, absolutly, my script1 and 2 are totally independent from each others but they have their own library to import.